# Loud bass sound penetrating my bedroom at night

Tags: walls

In the past two months I've begun to hear a loud bass sound at night. I live in a quiet neighborhood. There is a main road that runs by it, but is buffered by houses, some trees and a creek. I've lived here nearly 10 years and never had this problem. I'm also deaf in one ear and partially deaf in the other. I've asked nearby neighbors and they don't hear it! When I try to walk around to find its location, no luck. It's not as loud outside! I don't know if it's a neighbor playing music, or someone driving around. I'm wondering if any devices available that detect location of such sounds. It's wrecking my evenings! Thank you!

Comment: If your neighbours can not hear it then it has to be within your house.  Also the definition of  bass sound is subjective.  Can you describe it more ?  Its is mono-tone ?

Comment: When it is making noise turn off all of the power and see if it quits. If so then turn on the breakers one at a time and note which one causes the power. Determine what that controls and you should have the source of noise if it is electrically generated. I am assuming the noise is continuous not cyclelic. Let us know what you find.

Comment: Sometimes appliances like furnaces or AC units will make vibrations that travel through floor or walls. Sometimes external large engine vehicles like trains, ships or even parked and idling semi trucks will send low frequency noises long distances. A few years ago, a construction site 2 blocks away from me was running a portable generator only at night to power their lights; it took me a week to figure out that the late-night low-frequency sounds were coming from there. Sometimes low-freq noise can be conducted to your house by pipes even.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [We hear a constant bass subwoofer like thumping noise every night from about midnight to 7 am](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/we-hear-a-constant-bass-subwoofer-like-thumping-noise-every-night-from-about-mid)  Or this one: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/33064/18078 Try throwing your main breaker to turn of all electrical in your house - but sound can focus in funny ways, so it could well be coming from outside, yet not be noticed by your neightbors.

Comment: It could be an outside sound, e.g., https://original.newsbreak.com/@inspire-wonderland-1604871/2908230806824-global-hum-the-mysterious-sound-that-s-been-keeping-residents-awake-for-decades . Also, do you live near high-tension power lines or radio transmitters?